# Connected graph task using JSfiddle

Tags: javascript, web, jsfiddle

I want to design a test task that the user should try to connect characters by order. For example connect (1) to (2) then (2) to (3).

I have used JSfiddle, and created circles. Every time I refresh it the location of the circles changes, how can I make the circles at specific order?

```
(function() {

var width = 900,
    height = 650;

var radius = 30; /* radius of circles */
var numCircles = 10; /* number of circles - you must update link source/target values to match changes in the number of circles */

var d3color = d3.interpolateRgb("#BAE4B3", "#006D2C"); /* color range for flow lines */

//A LIST OF LINKS BETWEEN CIRCLES
var links = [
    {
    source: 0,
    target: 5,
    strength: Math.round(Math.random() * 10)},
{
    source: 0,
    target: 2,
    strength: Math.round(Math.random() * 10)},
{
    source: 1,
    target: 3,
    strength: Math.round(Math.random() * 10)},
{
    source: 2,
    target: 4,
    strength: Math.round(Math.random() * 10)},
{
    source: 3,
    target: 5,
    strength: Math.round(Math.random() * 10)},
{
    source: 5,
    target: 0,
    strength: Math.round(Math.random() * 10)},
{
    source: 2,
    target: 0,
    strength: Math.round(Math.random() * 10)},
{
    source: 3,
    target: 1,
    strength: Math.round(Math.random() * 10)}
];

function createDefs(defs) {
    var dropShadowFilter = defs.append('svg:filter').attr('id', 'dropShadow');
    dropShadowFilter.append('svg:feGaussianBlur').attr('in', 'SourceAlpha').attr('stdDeviation', 1);
    dropShadowFilter.append('svg:feOffset').attr('dx', 0).attr('dy', 1).attr('result', 'offsetblur');
    var feMerge = dropShadowFilter.append('svg:feMerge');
    feMerge.append('svg:feMergeNode');
    feMerge.append('svg:feMergeNode').attr('in', "SourceGraphic");
}

var drag = d3.behavior.drag().origin(Object).on("drag", function() {
    dragmove(this);
});

//RANDOMLY GENERATE COORDINATES FOR CIRCLES
var circles = d3.range(numCircles).map(function(i, d) {
    return [Math.round(50 + (i / numCircles) * (width - 50)), Math.round(30 + Math.random() * (height - 80))];
});

//GLOBAL STRENGTH SCALE
var strength_scale = d3.scale.linear().range([2, 10]) /* thickness range for flow lines */
.domain([0, d3.max(links, function(d) {
    return d.strength;
})]);

var color_scale = d3.scale.linear().range([0, 1]).domain([0, d3.max(links, function(d) {
    return d.strength;
})]);

var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg").attr("width", width).attr("height", height);

var g_lines = svg.append("g").attr("class", "lines");
var g_circles = svg.append("g").attr("class", "circles");
var g_midpoints = svg.append("g").attr("class", "midpoints");

//SHADOW DEFINITION
createDefs(svg.append('svg:defs'));

$.each(circles, function(i, d) {
    g_circles.append("circle").attr('filter', 'url(#dropShadow)').attr("class", "circle").attr("id", "circle" + i).attr("r", radius).attr("cx", d[0]).attr("cy", d[1]).call(drag);
});

g_lines.selectAll(".link_line").data(links).enter().append("path").attr("class", "link_line").attr("fill", function(d) {
    return d3color(color_scale(d.strength));
}).attr("id", function(i, d) {
    return "link_line" + d;
}).attr("d", function(d) {
    return drawCurve(d);
});

function dragmove(dragged) {
    var x = d3.select(dragged).attr("cx");
    var y = d3.select(dragged).attr("cy");
    d3.select(dragged).attr("cx", Math.max(radius, Math.min(width - radius, +x + d3.event.dx))).attr("cy", Math.max(radius, Math.min(height - radius, +y + d3.event.dy)));
    $.each(links, function(i, link) {
        if (link.source == dragged.id.match(/\d+/)[0] || link.target == dragged.id.match(/\d+/)[0]) {
            d3.select('#link_line' + i).attr("d", function(d) {
                return drawCurve(d);
            });
        }
    });
}

function drawCurve(d) {
    var slope = Math.atan2((+d3.select('#circle' + d.target).attr("cy") - d3.select('#circle' + d.source).attr("cy")), (+d3.select('#circle' + d.target).attr("cx") - d3.select('#circle' + d.source).attr("cx")));
    var slopePlus90 = Math.atan2((+d3.select('#circle' + d.target).attr("cy") - d3.select('#circle' + d.source).attr("cy")), (+d3.select('#circle' + d.target).attr("cx") - d3.select('#circle' + d.source).attr("cx"))) + (Math.PI / 2);

    var sourceX = +d3.select('#circle' + d.source).attr("cx");
    var sourceY = +d3.select('#circle' + d.source).attr("cy");
    var targetX = +d3.select('#circle' + d.target).attr("cx");
    var targetY = +d3.select('#circle' + d.target).attr("cy");

    var arrowOffset = 20;
    var points = [];
    points.push([sourceX + radius * Math.cos(slope) - strength_scale(d.strength) * Math.cos(slopePlus90), sourceY + radius * Math.sin(slope) - strength_scale(d.strength) * Math.sin(slopePlus90)]);
    points.push([sourceX + radius * Math.cos(slope), sourceY + radius * Math.sin(slope)]);
    points.push([targetX - radius * Math.cos(slope), targetY - radius * Math.sin(slope)]);
    points.push([targetX - (radius + arrowOffset) * Math.cos(slope) - strength_scale(d.strength + (arrowOffset / 2)) * Math.cos(slopePlus90), targetY - (radius + arrowOffset) * Math.sin(slope) - strength_scale(d.strength + (arrowOffset / 2)) * Math.sin(slopePlus90)]);
    points.push([targetX - (radius + arrowOffset) * Math.cos(slope) - strength_scale(d.strength) * Math.cos(slopePlus90), targetY - (radius + arrowOffset) * Math.sin(slope) - strength_scale(d.strength) * Math.sin(slopePlus90)]);
    return d3LineLinear(points) + "Z";
}
})();
```

Comment: Jung is a good one

Comment: Hi @tofi, now that you've updated your question please also update your tags, since it seems we're talking about a JavaScript problem (i.e., not python or java) anymore :)

Answer (score 0):

JUNG is a good option for visualisation, and also has a fairly good set of available graph algorithms, including several different mechanisms for random graph creation, rewiring, etc. I've also found it to be generally fairly easy to extend and adapt where necessary.

Or JGraphT, simple, yet powerful API:

```
UndirectedGraph<String, DefaultEdge> g =
    new SimpleGraph<String, DefaultEdge>(DefaultEdge.class);

String v1 = "v1";
String v2 = "v2";
String v3 = "v3";
String v4 = "v4";

// add the vertices
g.addVertex(v1);
g.addVertex(v2);
g.addVertex(v3);
g.addVertex(v4);

// add edges to create a circuit
g.addEdge(v1, v2);
g.addEdge(v2, v3);
g.addEdge(v3, v4);
g.addEdge(v4, v1);
```